# Set color of sphere as a function of coordinates in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Given this basic sphere rendering in three.js, how can I modify it so the color of the sphere is a function of the coordinates on the sphere? For example, the make the top half of the sphere red and the bottom half black?

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 500 / 400, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(500, 400);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);


camera.position.z = 10;
var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    cube.rotation.y += 0.001;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, you can check y-coordinate of a sphere's face's normal, and if it's greater than 0, then it means that the face is at the top half, otherwise it's at the bottom half.

[image]

```
var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 32, 24);
sphereGeom.faces.forEach(function(face){ // loop through faces
    if (face.normal.y > 0) // check y-coordinate of a face's normal
    face.color.setHex(0xFF0000); // set the color of the face (red)
    else
    face.color.setHex(0x000000); // set the color of the face (black)
})

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom, new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors // use face colors
}));
scene.add(sphere);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/2vke0o5s/) example.

But this is a particular case. For more complex geometries you can check coordinates of vertices of faces. Like this: `geometry.vertices[face.a]` - here we found coordinates of the a-vertex of a face in the array of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

For example, how about such a change?

Change from "MeshNormalMaterial" to "MeshLambertMaterial"

Add ambient light

Add spot light

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 500 / 400, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(500, 400);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

// Ambient light
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x707070);
// Spot light
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xff0000,0.8);
directionalLight.position.set(-60,60,0);
scene.add( ambientLight, directionalLight);

camera.position.z = 10;
var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    cube.rotation.y += 0.001;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```